# Changing the axis labels in a group of stacked bar charts

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following code

```
library(tibble)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

test <- tibble(
  cat1 = c(rep('foo',6),rep('bar',6)),
  cat2 = rep(c('g1','g2','g3','g4','g5','g6'), 2),
  zoom = rnorm(12, 0, 10),
  zaps = rnorm(12, 5, 10),
  buzz = rnorm(12, -5, 10)
) %>% pivot_longer(c(zoom,zaps,buzz),names_to = 'cat3', values_to='value')

test2 <- inner_join(test, summarise(group_by(test, cat1, cat2), agg = sum(value)))

ggplot(test2, aes(x = cat1, y = value, fill = cat3, label = as.integer(value))) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity', position = 'stack') +
  geom_text(position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5), size = 3, color = "#555555") +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = agg, ymax = agg)) +
  facet_grid(~ cat2)
```

which produces the following chart:
[image]

I like this and I am mostly happy with it, but I would love to include a sum total label for each column (the same value as the horizontal black line) somewhere in the column, ideally either at the bottom above/below the x axis labels or above the top edge of the plot below the g1,g2...
Can I do this by changing the displayed labels soo foo in g1 would be 'foo\n8' ? or is there a generic way to tell ggplot to put a number above the bar/foo labels in the plot or above the top edge of the top column component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this way. Please let me know if I miss something or I'm wrong with your purpose.

```
df2 %>% 
  group_by(cat1, cat2) %>%
  mutate(n = sum(as.integer(value))) %>%
  rowwise %>%
  mutate(cat1 = paste0(c(cat1, n), collapse = "\n")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = cat1, y = value, fill = cat3, label = as.integer(value))) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity', position = 'stack') +
  geom_text(position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5), size = 3, color = "#555555") +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = agg, ymax = agg)) +
  facet_wrap(~ cat2, scales = "free_x", ncol = 6)
```

[image]

Comment: I like this, is there a risk that the order of ```labelss``` won't match the order that ggplot puts the columns in, though?

Comment: @Guillermo I find some problem in my answer and I'm trying to fix it. I'll reply you again after I fix this. I'm sorry.

Comment: @Guillermo I edit the code. I think it's much better now. If there's any question or anything else, please let me know.